# When is IMap entrylistiner predicate evaluated

Tags: hazelcast

I had a question regarding 
`addEntryListener(EntryListener<K,V> listener, Predicate<K,V> predicate,boolean includeValue)` in IMap interface. Any clarification is appreciated.

Javadoc says

> Listener will get notified for map add/remove/update/evict events
>   filtered by given predicate

I assume that for every map update, the predicate is evaluated first and listeners are notified(Value transferred over the wire) only when the predicate is satisfied, rather than all updates transferred over the wire first and then the listeners evaluating the predicate.

Is this assumption right ?

Comment: Good question. 

My bet is that all updates are send and filtering is done at the receiving side. 

I'll ask how this part is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Predicates are evaluated at the source, not the destination. So if a predicate rejects something, the value will not be send to the listener.

So your assumption is correct.